# Solving for a One-time pad cipher help ; crib dragging doesnt work (no surprise)

Tags: one-time-pad

Basically we're given the text

> 7ECC555AB95BF6EC605E5F22B772D2B34FF4636340D32FABC29B
>   73CB4855BE44F6EC60594C2BB47997B60EEE303049CD3CABC29B
>   64C6401BAF45F6A930435F3DF875C4E102F8742A45C824AFCA9B
>   7AC24F5EAF17F0A0754D5834BC3CC3A90ABD7B2A52C222ABC89B
>   72C24A52B550B3B8624D4F22F86BD2B30ABD642C498122A1D29B
>   73CC5457BF17E7A4750C5423B178D0A44FFF756355C03CABC28A
>   74CC0155B443B3A8795F4224AA7E97B507F2632606CF3FA0D59B

And what we have to do is solve this, I understand the fact that if used properly the one-time pad is uncrackable but in this case we abuse the fact that certain characters are repeating ("ABC" and/or "AB") and have to use XOR in the process some how, unfortunately the problem is that it wasnt very well explained how to solve and other online resources dont really explain it very well in my opinion

How does one go about solving this?

Comment: Is that actually a multi-time pad?  That is, several different texts were all encrypted with the same one-time pad?

Comment: Yes, each line is a separate english sentence

Comment: I understand the concept behind the one-time pad encryption but the problem I have is specifically how to solve it. 

E.g How do you go about XOR'ing 7EC with 73C? I assume the post I made in the OP is in Hex, do I convert to Binary and then XOR the equivalents? 

Also how do I get a 'randomly generated key' and what is it meant to do?

Comment: Have you actually read the answer in the duplicate?  It spells out fairly clearly how to solve it

Comment: Oh I just saw that further down now, but how does one XOR two encrypted messages if theyre not 1's and 0's?

Comment: I want to do it without using the program the he links to

Comment: Still stuck and clueless

Answer (score 0):

Take the ASCII values of each letter , convert them to binary and xor them with characters you think it may be. You can do it manually or have the internet tell you each characters values. Just from what I read from the link posted it above it shouldn't be that difficult to do. Since this cipher you have has a lot of repeats, you should be able to crack it fairly easy follow the previous posts guide.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, whenever I use his 'crib dragging' technique I keep getting things like ~nd, suj , igb , {oz , swe , khe

Comment: Can you state the actual question? Are there any hints in it? The letters look like hex values since it never goes F, so im sure what exactly they want from you

Comment: A number of valid English sentences are encrypted using the same one-time pad key. Shown below are the encrypted sentences, and you are asked to decrypt them.

It is likely that the solution will require a mixture of automated analysis and guess work. Once you have decrypted the sentences, please write down in the answer sheet the decrypted form of the first sentence given above. Please ensure you use the correct case.

__
Thats all thats given

Comment: pretty much stumped at the moment, dont know what to do

Comment: yeah me too, I ran some frequencies stuff and a few other decrypting programs, but couldn't get anything. It seems easy since it's only using 16 characters and they repeat a lot, but I am not to advanced on the subject to give you anymore help. sorry

Comment: @Thrall it's hex encoded, so that's why you only see 16 characters. ASCII bytes xored with random bytes, encoded as hex (2 characters per byte).